# ramda/functional programming - different logic based on condition

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm new to functional programming and I want to go through a collection and find an element based on a condition. The condition is as follows but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to write it in an functional way (below uses Ramda):

```
import * as R from "ramda";

const data = [{x: 0, y: 0} , {x: 1, y: 0}];

//return the cell which matches the coord on the given orientation
function findCell(orientation, coord) {

  const search = R.find(cell => {
    if (orientation === "x") {
      return cell.x === coord;
    } else {
      return cell.y === coord;
    }
  });

  return search(data);
}

findCell("x", 0);
```

Is there a more elegant way to write this predicate in either Ramda or some other functional JS library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R.propEq is a fitting predicate for what you're looking for (find by property value). Use R.pipe to create a function that accepts property and value, passes them to R.propEq, and returns an R.find function with the predicate.

```js
const { pipe, propEq, find } = R;

const findCell = pipe(propEq, find);

const data = [{x: 0, y: 0} , {x: 1, y: 0}];

const result = findCell('x', 0)(data);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

You can do the same thing with vanilla JS using `Array.find()`:

```js
const findCell = (prop, value, arr) => arr.find(o => o[prop] === value)

const data = [{x: 0, y: 0} , {x: 1, y: 0}];

const result = findCell('x', 0, data);

console.log(result);
```